# vectorized addition of parameterized arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I'd like to sum a series of vectors defined by a (complicated) function of parameters.  Is there a way to use vectorization in place of the nested for loop to get the same value for `ans` in the code below?  Memory usage is not to be a constraint.  Note that for the actual problem the nested for loop is known to limit performance, despite this not being the case here.

```
import numpy as np

a1_vec = np.array([0.3, 1])
a2_vec = np.array([3.3, 10])
b1_vec = np.array([0.5, 0.7])
b2_vec = np.array([1.5, 1.3])

x = np.arange(0, 10000)
ans = 0
for a1, b1 in zip(a1_vec, b1_vec):
    for a2, b2 in zip(a2_vec, b2_vec):
        ans += x*np.exp(- a1 - b2) + x**(1 / 2)*np.cos(b1) + x**(1 / 3)*np.sin(a2)
```

Comment: `x[:,None,None] * np.exp(-a1_vec[None,None,:]-b2_vec[None,:,None]` should give a (10000,2,2) array, which can be `np.sum(...)`.  Similarly for the other terms

Comment: @hpaulj can you say more about what you've put in the comment?  I'm happy to accept if you add an answer.

Comment: interesting - the nested loop code is actually faster.  I  wonder if there is a faster way to do this with numpy, cython?

Comment: that is indeed interesting and unexpected, apparently python3 actually stepped up it's game. Does that even hold for longer x vectors? so 1e5 or 1e6 in the arange?

Comment: another thing you could try is [numba][http://numba.pydata.org/] where the code is complied. I'd try this before cython. In all fairness, your problem seems small enough, why would you want to optimize further?

Comment: It's only 4 iterations, on a complex task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as @anon pointed out in his comment, you can use numpy's array [broadcasting](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_broadcasting.htm):
using `X[:,None,None]` or the more explicit `X[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]` (which just is an more explicit alias for `None`). With this `np.newaxis`, you can introduce a new, empty dimension into your array. Your `X.shape` (dimensionality of the array) will be no longer be `(10000)` but `(10000,1,1)`.

Any operation on two arrays needs the same dimensions on both arrays (e.g. `(2,5)` and `(2,5)` will work). One of the cool features of numpy is the broadcasting, which happens when an array operation is done between two arrays where one dimension that is larger than 1 is combined with a dimension of 1 (e.g. `(2,5)` and `(2,1)` where the second dimension is 5 in the first and 1 in the second vector). In this case numpy will broadcast the array with the dimension of 1 by simply looping over it (and it will do so in a c-compiled fast way). In the example it will take the of the `(2,5)` array with the `(2,1)` array it will pretend that the second array is also a `(2,5)` array just with the same two numbers 5 times repeated.

so as an easy example look at

```
a = np.arange(3)
print(a*a)
#[0,2,4]
```

this is just normal element by element multiplication

now if you introduce empty dimensions using broadcasting rules:

```
print(a[:,None]*a[None,:])
#[[0 0 0]
# [0 1 2]
# [0 2 4]]
```

It's a really cool and the very key to understanding the power of numpy, but admittedly it also took me some time to get familiar with it.